# data munging in python compared with R (from an excel sheet)

Tags: python, r, excel, data-munging

I have a hypothetical example here with file attached [(Excel File Link)](http://www.filedropper.com/sample_9) where I'm loading in a file from excel and formatting it into something I can work with to either analyse or store more permanently.

In R I would use the following few lines to make it usable:

```
library(gdata)
tmp = read.xls('~/Desktop/sample.xlsx',1,stringsAsFactors=F)
tmp = tmp[,!sapply(tmp,function(x)all(is.na(x)))]
tmp$date = tmp[1,2]
for(i in 2:ncol(tmp)){ifelse(tmp[2,i]=='',tmp[2,i]<-tmp[2,i-1],tmp[2,i]<-tmp[2,i])}
tmp[2,1]=tmp[1,1]
names(tmp)=paste(tmp[2,],tmp[3,],sep='.')
tmp=tmp[-c(1:3),]
names(tmp)[10]='date'
```

In python - I've gotten as far as

```
import xlrd

myf='/home/me/Desktop/sample.xlsx'

sheet = xlrd.open_workbook(myf).sheet_by_index(0)

s1=[]
r = sheet.nrows
c = sheet.ncols
for row in range(0,r):
    t1=[]
    for col in range(0,c):
        t1.append(sheet.cell_value(row,col))
    s1.append(t1)
```

but then I've had very little success getting rid of empty rows and columns. All of the following fail.

```
>>> s1[0]
['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
>>> s1[0] == []
False
>>> s1[0] == ''
False
>>> s1[0] == all('')
False
```

so I'm not even too clear how I check that the entire list is empty.

I can zip the rows 2 & 3 (5 & 6 in python)

```
>>> zip(s1[5],s1[6])
[('', ''), (u'cat1', u'a'), ('', u'b'), ('', ''), (u'cat2', u'c'), ('', u'd'), ('', ''), (u'cat3', u'e'), ('', u'f'), ('', ''), (u'cat4', u'g'), ('', u'h')]
```

but I don't know how I'd get that to paste forwards in a for-next loop.

Very n00b question reflective of my understanding of python as is. Any thoughts would be most welcome. Submitted with some trepidation because I recognize the question has a 'homework' feel even though it is actually a personal learning exercise. Thanks

after a bit of messing about I've worked up a rough and ready working example below: Would be grateful for pointers on how to do it more efficiently.

I had a try at pandas but found the learning curve quite steep. If someone could post a working MWE I'd be pleased to mark it answered.

```
import os
import xlrd
import pandas as pd
import pprint
import re
import csv

''' 
Create a few helper functions to save time 
finding things, picking empties and selecting items
'''

def nulls(x):
    g = lambda r: all(i == '' for i in r)
    out = [i for i,j in enumerate(x) if g(j)]
    return(out)

def fill(x):
    for i in range(1,len(x)):
        if x[i] == '':
            x[i] = x[i-1]
    return(x)

def which(x,y):
    out = [i for i,j in enumerate(x) if y(j) ]
    return(out)

def T(x):
    out = map(list,zip(*x))
    return(out)

def rbind(x,y,sep=None):
    if sep is None:
        sep='.'
    out = [str(i[0]) + sep + str(i[1]) for i in zip(x,y)]
    return(out)

# def csvit(x):
#   tmp = next(key for key,val in globals().items() if val == x and not key.startswith('_'))
#   f=open('/home/me/Desktop/csvs/'+tmp+'.csv','wb')
#   writer = csv.writer(f,quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL,dialect=csv.excel)
#   [writer.writerow(i) for i in x]
#   f.close()


#
# Load spreadsheet from file and convert to python list
#

sheet = xlrd.open_workbook('/home/me/Downloads/sample.xlsx').sheet_by_index(0)
s = [sheet.row_values(i) for i in range(sheet.nrows)]

#
# Get rid of unnecessary excel formatting and spacing
#

# rows first
s = [j for i,j in enumerate(s) if i not in nulls(s)]

# transpose & then columns (surely there is a more elegant way?)
s = T(s)
s = [j for i,j in enumerate(s) if i not in nulls(s)]

# get title for primary category column
title = s[0][0]

# get date for secondary category column
date = [j[1] for j in s if str(j[0]) == 'date']

#
# combine columns into a single category variable (could also have left them separate)
#

cols=['Category']
s = T(s)
cols.extend(rbind(fill(s[2]),s[3])[1:])
s = s[4:len(s)] 

s=T(s)
category = [str(i) for i in s[0]]
s=s[1:len(s)]

c1=[date for i in range(len(s[0]))] #create date column
c2=[title for i in range(len(s[0]))] #create title column
cols.insert(0,'title')
cols.insert(1,'date')
s.insert(0,c2)
s.insert(1,c1)

s = T(s)
```

Comment: Using ifelse inside an R loop like that is highly inefficient. That's where `if(.){ } else{ }` is appropriate. The `ifelse( , , )` construct is designed to avoid the loop. Furthermore putting assingments inside an `ifelse()` function is "just wrong".

Comment: Thanks @DWin will keep it in mind. This was a quick kludge for illustration, in practice, in R I have a utility function to 'hfill' a vector.

Comment: For more complete data analysis support look at this - http://pandas.pydata.org/

Answer (score 1):

This is just a suggestion: if it's possible that you can export your excel worksheet as a csv, you might want to have a look at `numpy.genfromtxt`: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.io.genfromtxt.html

It seems to have similar capabilities to pandas but without the steep learning curve. has `delimiter`, `autostrip`, `missing_values`, `filling_values`, column `names`, and the columns are in `numpy.array` form.